# Converting to Chomsky Normal Form from a CFG?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

Consider the context-free grammar G = ( { S, B, E }, { 0, 1, i, e, s }, R, S ), where R is:

```
S --> iBSE | s
B --> 0 | 1
E --> lambda | eS
```

Alrighty, so I removed the lambda and got:

```
S0 --> S
S --> iBS | iBSE | s
B --> 0 | 1
E --> eS
```

And now I'm trying to remove the unit/chain rules and the rest, and this is what I have so far:

```
S0 --> X
X --> YS
S --> BS
S --> BSE
S --> s
B --> 0
B --> 1
E --> ZS
Y --> i
Z --> e
```

But I know S0 --> X and S --> BSE are not valid. How can I fix this? Thank you for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you create X?
If so, `S0-->S` is a better idea. Then, to remove the S's from the right hand side of S should be done with non-terminals.

`S0 --> S
S --> BS | BSE | s`

You want to replace things like BS with a non-terminal:

`S --> P | PE | s
P --> BS` 
If you could specify what the context was (for lambda, and what you're using for epsilon, I might be able to be of more help, but there are a lot of Theory of Computation slides that google can find for you, and they are pretty helpful themselves (if you get the right ones).